# Can't get list of users using Admin SDK Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

If I add to the Firebase cloud functions, I cannot get a list of users. I have tried many things, and followed the guide on firebase documentation, but it just keeps running, but never loading.

```
exports.listAllUsers = functions.https.onRequest((data, context) => {
  // List all users

  return listAllUsers();
});

function listAllUsers() {
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  var allUsers = [];

  return admin.auth().listUsers()
    .then(function (listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function (userRecord) {
        // For each user
        var userData = userRecord.toJSON();
        allUsers.push(userData);
      });
        return allUsers
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be confusing two types of Cloud functions:

1. Callable functions, that you call from your app using the Firebase SDK.
2. Regular HTTP functions, that you call from your app your client platform's regular HTTP client API.

#### Cloud Functions that are invoked with regular HTTPS requests

When you declare your function as `functions.https.onRequest`, you need to write your response to the response object. Based on the [documentation on calling functions through HTTP requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), you'll need to do:

```
exports.listAllUsers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  var allUsers = [];

  return admin.auth().listUsers()
    .then(function (listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function (userRecord) {
        // For each user
        var userData = userRecord.toJSON();
        allUsers.push(userData);
      });
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(allUsers));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});
```

#### Calling Cloud Functions that are invoked using the Firebase SDK

If you want to [call your Cloud Function from within your app using the Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), you need to declare your function as:

```
exports.listAllUsers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // List all users

  return listAllUsers();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I am having trouble with the calling side, this originally worked but now not, var listAllUsers = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('listAllUsers');
                    listAllUsers({}).then(function(result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    });

Comment: Aha, so you are indeed trying to implement a Callable function. In that case you should use the second approach from my answer to fix the problem with the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I have looked at the guide, and changed to return {userList:listAllUsers()}; but this just the returns null. I know this to not be true, and works fine with onRequest